# Boost page with specific fonts in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax, dismax

I crawled a website with Apache Nutch and index it to Apache Solr.How i can boost a document that query word exist in specific font(like h2 html tag or...)? for example my query is book and there are two page that contain book. in first page book is in h1 html tag and in second page book is in h2 html tag. i want that second page come in upper result(have bigger boost).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think PayLoads (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-755) will help in your case (Scoring certain occurrences of a term higher than others).

Check http://edwarddrapkin.com/2011/04/14/an-introduction-to-lucene-payloads/ for detailed explanation.